# C++ code is ported to the NDK environment and the header file like windows.h is missing?

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, android-mediaplayer

Recently I am doing my undergraduate graduation project, which is an Android-based DMB player (relying on DAB broadcast radio signals).

The reference materials my instructor gave me are all Windows-based players, and I am porting some C++ code I encountered some problems when I was working. For example, afxwin.h and windows.h were introduced into many of the C++ codes that my instructor gave me.

My job is Java server development, and I am an Android novice and a C++ novice.

The missing header file looks like this

```c
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "mpeg_dec.h"
```

```c
#include <afxwin.h>         // MFC core and standard components
#include <afxext.h>         // MFC extensions
#include <afxdisp.h>        // MFC Automation classes
#include <afxdtctl.h>       // MFC support for Internet Explorer 4 Common Controls
```

Thank you for your answers, it will be a huge help to me (by the way, I am a student from China, English writing is not my strong point, so some of the above are from Google Translate, thank you for understanding!)

Comment: `stdafx.h` is used with visual studio if compiling with pre-compiled headers and is a cue for the compiler to look for precompiled headers for Microsoft Foundation Classes (afx) or windows specific headers to speed up compilation. `windows.h` is part of the windows API and, from memory, includes other windows API headers. To port to Android, you will need to rewrite code to use either an Android-specific library or a library that supports Android. Unless the API under Android looks a lot like Microsoft APIs (unlikely, but not impossible) the logic of your code will need to change.

Comment: Similarly, MFC stands for Microsoft Foundation Classes and is an app framework from the 1990's. Not part of any Android tools, of course.